# Repeating Capture Groups Regex

Tags: regex, capture-group

I have a large chunk of class data that I need to run a regular expression on and get data back from. The problem is that I need a repeating capturing group in order to acomplish that.

```
Womn St  157A      QUEERHISTORY MAKING
    CCode Typ Sec Unt  Instructor         Time              Place     Max   Enr Req Rstr Status 
    32680 LEC A   4    SHAH, P.           TuTh 11:00-12:20p IAB 131    35    37 60       FULL

Womn St  171       SEX/RACE & CONQUEST
    CCode Typ Sec Unt  Instructor         Time              Place     Max   Enr Req Rstr Status 
    32710 LEC A   4    O'TOOLE, R.        TuTh  2:00- 3:20p DBH 1300   52 13/45 24       OPEN   
      ~ Same as 25610 (GlblClt 103B, Lec A);  26350 (History 169, Lec A);  and
      ~    60320 (Anthro 139, Lec B).
    32711 DIS 1   0    MONSON, A.         W     9:00- 9:50  HH 105     25  5/23 8        OPEN   
                       O'TOOLE, R.                                                              
      ~ Same as 25612 (GlblClt 103B, Dis 1);  26351 (History 169, Dis 1);  and
      ~    60321 (Anthro 139, Dis 1).
```

The result I need would return two matches

1. Match
   Group1:Womn St 157A
   Group2:QUEERHISTORY MAKING
   Group3:32680
   Group4:LEC
   Group5:A
   Group6:SHAH, P.
   Group7:TuTh 11:00-12:20p
   Group8:IAB 13
2. Match 
   Group1:Womn St 171
   Group2:SEX/RACE & CONQUEST
   Group3:32710
   Group4:LEC
   Group5:A
   Group6:O'TOOLE, R.
   Group7:TuTh  2:00- 3:20p
   Group8:DBH 1300
   Group9:25610
   Group10:26350
   Group11:60320
   Group12:32711
   Group13:DIS
   Group14:1
   Group15:MONSON, A.
   Group16: W    9:00- 9:50
   Group17:HH 105
   Group18:25612
   Group19:26351
   Group20:60321

Comment: What is the language you are using? Anyway, I feel that you should read the records line by line and parse them. The data is rather nicely formatted. Writing a big regex to parse this is possible, but I wouldn't do it.

Comment: What is your regexp so far? I would suggest one regexp per line/(sub)dataset.

Comment: Have you got some code to show?